# Vee-Validate 3.x on VueJS & Vuetify project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I am trying to use Vee Validate 3.x on a VueJS - Vuetify project for a bit now.
Either I am misunderstanding this or the docs are just horribly inaccurate...

Here is what I have

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import VueRouter from './routes';
import {ValidationProvider} from 'vee-validate';
import i18n from './i18n';
import { extend } from 'vee-validate';
import { required } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';


// Register it globally
Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);
// Add the required rule
extend('required', {
  ...required,
  message: 'This field is required'
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router: VueRouter,
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**some component**

```
    <ValidationProvider name="email" rules="required|email" v-slot="{ errors }">
    <v-text-field
      v-model="lineItem.name"
      @input="$emit('update:lineItem', $event)"
      required
    />
      <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
    </ValidationProvider>
```

I keep ending up with `Unknown custom element: <ValidationProvider> - did you register the component correctly?`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this documentation they register the component within the vue initialisation: https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/

Comment: Hm, what i noted above, does seem to work now.
I have a mixup in my syntax :-(
The one you link to, does not seem to work for me...
Djeez, is it just me or is this docu on vee-validate really scattered?

Comment: Your code in the question looks fine, and as you say if it’s now working then it could be a caching issue.